# Scaling doesn't work in the 23 and 27 inch screens

Tags: xaml, windows-8, responsive-design, scale

I have two UserControls that have a Grid each. The first one defines a Height and a Width:

```
<UserControl
    Height="620"
    Width="450">

   <Grid Margin="50, 0, 0, 50">
```

The other control only defines the Height:

```
<UserControl
    Height="768">
    <Grid>
```

Now I am trying to use both in a background like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Assets/background.png" Stretch ="UniformToFill" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Controls:EventImagesControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Controls:ScrollControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>            
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Everything scales as I was expecting in the following settings:

```
10.6" 1024x768
10.6" 1366x768
10.6" 1920x1080
10.6" 2560x1440
12"   1280x800
```

However, when I try to use the following settings it only scales in width and not in height (at least it seems)

```
23" 1920x1080
27" 2560x1440
```

I am trying to avoid the usage of a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox.aspx). I am new to the windows8/wpf, but I am trying to learn how to do a responsive layout.

Comment: To create a responsive layout, first get rid of fixed width and height (or set it to Auto), then make your controls to fit in the grid, and set both the horizontal and vertical aligment to stretch.

Comment: I thought my controls were already set to stretch in both alignments? I need to give some kind of dimensions... Imagine that a control has some images that I want to display in specific positions. This control is used in the Grid and has to scale. Note that the way I did it it works in several resolutions in two screen sizes but it doesn't work on 23" and 27" screen sizes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinRT rendering engine scales so everything is physically correct, that's why the 4 10.6" tests look the same size, no matter the resolution of the screen. The 12" test scales nicely, but as it's size is close to the 10.6" and you won't notice a difference (althought there's a difference), the biggest screen sizes will scale so your 450x620 control look like a 450x620 control an a 23" Full HD screen, this means an small control.

Actually, the link you posted describes nicely every type of scaling you can use in a Modern UI app. And if you really need to set a minimum size, use the MinWidth and MinHeight properties instead.

Comment: So the only way I can stretch for all resolutions is with ViewBox? Also, how can I define two layouts (for 4:3 and 16:9) when I use ViewBox so I can avoid the letterbox the Windows uses?

Comment: I started a new question to find out how to create two layouts for two aspect ratios. If you can help here is the link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843213/defining-two-layouts-for-two-aspect-ratios-43-and-169