# Two layouts for two aspect ratios (4:3 and 16:9) - changing automatically

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-8, scale, aspect-ratio

Following [the Microsoft scale guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx) there is a part where it says:

> When designing a fixed layout, start by designing your layout for the baseline resolutions: 1024x768 and 1366x768.

Regarding this I have the following question:

Is it possible to define two fixed layouts for two aspect ratios (both to be used with the `ViewBox` to scale to every resolution in that aspect ratio) so they can change automatically depending on the screen's aspect ratio? And maybe change between the fill mode and full screen mode that also changes aspect ratios ?

Answer (score 0):

Project Templates comes with LayoutAwarePage that provides visual states you can use to change layout according to ApplicationView (Filled, Snapped etc...) If needed you could extend that behavior there overriding InvalidateVisualState.

Comment: Where can I find that LayoutAwarePage (in a blog I saw that it usually is in the Common folder but I haven't that). Also, my idea was to also support resolutions like 1024 x 768.

Comment: It is in grid application Template

Comment: I am not using a grid application template. I started as an empty application and I am not using a responsive layout (actually that is why I need two layouts for at least this two ratios)